# Drawing with OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, opengl

I'm working on a program which will calculate the centroids of some polygons. I have the centroid calculations in place. I would like to display the polygons with OpenGL. I have an OpenGL window up and running already.

In the OpenGL class there is a method, drawRect where you 'draw' the vertices to screen. I have however got the vertices I want to draw in a separate polygon class. Ideally I would like to call a draw method on a polygon, e.g.

```
firstPolygon.draw();
```

But I don't know how I would do that as the drawRect method is in the OpenGL class and thats the only way I know to draw. Can I somehow send data to the draw method from within the Polygon class? or draw directly to the screen within the polygon class?

Currently 'OpenGLView.m' contains:

```
#import "OpenGL/gl.h"
#import "OpenGLView.h"
#import "Poly.h"

@implementation OpenGLView

-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if(self){
         // initialise things here
    }    
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)Rect
{
    glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    {
        glVertex3f(  0.0,  0.6, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( -0.2, -0.3, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(  0.2, -0.3 ,0.0);
    }
    glEnd();

    // finish drawing
    glFlush();
}
@end
```

And the 'Polygon' class I would like to draw in this method so I can refer to the stored vertices easily..

```
-(void)drawPolygon
{
    // draw vertices
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call your `draw()` function from the context of the screen draw in opengl you should be okay. That means your `draw()` will have to still call the opengl appropriate draw calls of course.

I'm unfamiliar with opengl on objective-c but you can probably just pass the drawing context to the `draw()` function and have it call `drawRect` that way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow as the OpenGL class does not have an instance of a polygon object and the same with the polygon class not having an instance of an opengl class - so I'm not sure how to get them to communicate.

Comment: @PaulReed You can always add your own class that has a draw function that takes in the opengl class context.

Comment: Any ideas on how to pass the context? Usually I type in context when working on iOS but working on the Mac this is a little new.

Comment: Does my polygon class basically need to be a subclass of an OpenGL view then?

Comment: @PaulReed You just pass it as a function parameter (changed your draw() function to take a parameter of the open gl view).

Comment: I have done that, but when I draw objects using the simple glBegin(GL_LINE... etc.) nothing displays, it's not even cleared to the clear colour. It works within the openGL class but that's not where the vertices are.. :(